# R.js build doesn't follow require.config file

Tags: backbone.js, build, requirejs, marionette, r.js

I'm trying to build my single page application that uses Require.js, AMD style modules.

I already configured all the dependencies, paths and shims in my `init.js` file that runs first and then calls my `main.js` file.

Here is my `init.js` file :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var me = this;
    me.require.config({

        deps: ['backbone.marionette', 'main'],

        shim: {
            jquery: {
                exports: 'jQuery'
            },
            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            },
            backbone: {
                deps: [
                    'underscore',
                    'jquery'
                ],
                exports: 'Backbone'
            },
            'backbone.marionette': {
                deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
                exports: 'Marionette'
            }
        },

        paths: {
            jquery: '../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
            html5shiv: '../lib/html5shiv/html5shiv.js',
            underscore: '../lib/underscore/underscore-min',
            backbone: '../lib/backbone/backbone',
            'backbone.marionette': '../lib/backbone.marionette/lib/core/amd/backbone.marionette.min',
            'backbone.wreqr': '../lib/backbone.wreqr/lib/amd/backbone.wreqr.min',
            'backbone.babysitter': '../lib/backbone.babysitter/lib/amd/backbone.babysitter.min',
            text: '../lib/requirejs-text/text'
        }

    });
}).call(this);
```

and here is my `r.js` build config file :

```
({
    baseUrl: '../../development/js',
    optimize: 'closure',
    paths: {
        requireLib: '../lib/requirejs/require'
    },
    mainConfigFile: '../../development/js/init.js',
    out: '../../distribution/main-build.js',
    include: ['requireLib']
})
```

When I build, I only get Require.js inlined in my `main-build.js` file.

R.js doesn't follow the `deps` property defined in the require.config for some reason.

- Any ideas on how to get a single file containing my Backbone.js / Marionette.js files and the dependencies described in the `require.config` found in the `init.js` file ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if it is the way you defined your config. Is there any reason for the `init.js` as opposed to just putting the `require.config` in main? It seems unnecessary to create an anonymous function just to encapsulate it.

From the example [r.js build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27):

> The first requirejs({}), require({}), requirejs.config({}), or
>   require.config({}) call found in that file will be used.

What has always worked for me is to follow the more standard method of calling `require.config()` [inside main.js](https://github.com/simonsmith/modular-html-requirejs/blob/master/site/scripts/main.js)

Comment: Should I still set the `main.js` file as the mainConfigFile ? Or should I completely drop this property of the config ?

Comment: Yes, set `mainConfigFile` with a path to your `main.js`. The optimiser will parse out your call to `require.config()` and use that. Example - https://github.com/simonsmith/modular-html-requirejs/blob/master/build.js#L4

Comment: I made some tests and you were right ! The init.js file never called the main.js file. Thank you very much !